# Decimal precision using integer

Tags: c, printf

I am programming a uC in C language and I need to show a float number with 4 precision digits. The thing here is that my number is not really a float type. I have the integer part and the decimal part of the number in two different integer variables. Let say: int digit and int decimal.

I tried using printf ("%d.%d"); That works fine when my decimal number is 6524, but the problem comes when it is exactly 65 since it doesnt show 4 decimals.

I tried using printf ("%d.%04d"); but when my decimal part is exactly 65 it shows 0065 which is not mathematically correct (I would need 6500)

I looked for any argument of printf which completes with zeros at the end but could not find anything. All of them complete with leading zeros which is not useful for me in this case.

I also though about checking if my number is minor that 10, 100 or 1000 and multiply it by 1000, 100 or 10 respectively. But it will not work when the decimal part is exactly 0, since 0*1000 will still be 0 and not 0000.

Any idea on how to solve this? Please let me know if I am not completely clear and I will provide more information

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you should go further back, it must be a strange system that stores `.6500` as `65` but `.6524` as `6524`. Is this an X-Y question?

Comment: "decimal" is an encoding (base 10) and not a fraction (which you might mean). It's not quite clear what you mean. Please provide more details and/or use the correct terms. AS-is, it is hard to understand what you actually have and want.

Answer (score 1):

Since `printf` returns the number of characters printed, you can do it, somewhat clumsily, as follows:

```
printf("%d.", int_part);
int digits = printf("%d", frac_part);
while (digits++ < 4) putchar('0');
```

I have to say, though, that it is a *very* eccentric form of representing a floating point number, and you might seriously want to rethink it.

Answer (score 0):

Another wired possibility is to convert the decimal part to a string and then fill it with 0:

```
int main() {

    int i, d, len;
    char p[10];

    i = 189;
    d = 51;

    // convert the number to string and count the digits
    snprintf(p, 10, "%d", d);
    len = strlen(p);
    while (len < 4) {p[len] = '0'; len++;}
    p[len] = '\0';
    fprintf(stdout, "%d.%s\n", i, p);

    // you can also go back to int
    d = atoi(p);
    fprintf(stdout, "%d.%d\n", i, d);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine both your answers: multiply by `10`, `100` or `1000` as necessary, but still print with `%04d`.